# How to determine if a cv::Mat is a zero matrix?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, compare

I have a matrix that is dynamically being changed according to the following code;

```
 for( It=all_frames.begin(); It != all_frames.end(); ++It)
{
    ItTemp = *It;

    subtract(ItTemp, Base, NewData);

    cout << "The size of the new data for ";
    cout << " is \n" << NewData.rows << "x" << NewData.cols << endl;
    cout << "The New Data is: \n" << NewData << endl << endl;

    NewData_Vector.push_back(NewData.clone());

}
```

What I want to do is determine the frames at which the cv::Mat NewData is a zero matrix.
I've tried comparing it to a zero matrix that is of the same size, using both the cv::compare() function and simple operators (i.e NewData == NoData), but I can't even compile the program.

Is there a simple way of determining when a cv::Mat is populated by zeroes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I used

```
if (countNonZero(NewData) < 1) 
{
    cout << "Eye contact occurs in this frame" << endl;
}
```

This is a pretty simple (if perhaps not the most elegant) way of doing it.

Answer (score 28):

To check the mat if is empty, use `empty()`, if NewData is a cv::Mat, `NewData.empty()` returns true if there's no element in NewData.

To check if it's all zero, simply, `NewData == Mat::zeros(NewData.size(), NewData.type())`.

**Update:**

After checking the OpenCV source code, you can actually do `NewData == 0` to check all element is equal to 0.

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error message: could not convert ‘cv::operator==(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&)(((const cv::Mat&)((const cv::Mat*)(& cv::MatExpr::operator cv::Mat() const()))))’ to ‘bool’

Comment: I copied your line. Do you have code that compiles? What version of OpenCV? The header for cv::Mat shows no overload for the operator '=='

Comment: @Spaceghost,you can check your opencv's mat.hpp, there are something around line 1306. my current is the latest repo, but such function should be there since 2.0.

Comment: I copied your line and put an 'if' ahead of it.. and that seems to be the problem. Can you show your code in context?

Comment: Obviously, author didn't ask to check whether mat was empty. "Is there a simple way of determining when a cv::Mat is populated by zeroes?"

Answer (score 3):

countNonZero(Mat ) will give u number of non zeros in mat

Answer (score 1):

How about this..

```
Mat img = Mat::zeros(cvSize(1024, 1024), CV_8UC3);
bool flag = true;

MatConstIterator_<double> it = img.begin<double>();
MatConstIterator_<double> it_end = img.end<double>();
for(; it != it_end; ++it)
{
    if(*it != 0)
    {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Why iterator's argument is <double>, not the type of the matrix?

Comment: 2. Why C++ code is contaminated with C code? For example, there's cv::Size() instead of cvSize()

Answer (score 1):

The Mat object has an [empty](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a17d0777aef52a7cfbdb8d04d189fa5c3) property, so you can just ask Mat to tell you if it has something or it's empty. The result will be either `true` or `false`.