# Check if Mat is a black image

Tags: image, opencv, mat

Maybe an easy question but since I am a noob I dont know how to do it in an elegant way.
I am analyzing video. For that I am taking differences between the frames. If nothing has changed the resulting frame will be empty or black if I display it with imshow(...).
How do I find out if I am looking of one of these black (empty) frames?

I tried:

```
Mat threshold_output;
...
threshold_output.empty() --> does not work
or
threshold_output == 0 --> compiler error
```

Maybe someone can tell me :).

Thx

Comment: I think, you'll find your answer here :   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907574/how-to-determine-if-a-cvmat-is-a-zero-matrix

Comment: if (countNonZero(NewData) < 1) did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

you can use minMaxLoc and check whether maxVal == 0
:

```
// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
double minVal; double maxVal; 

minMaxLoc( threshold_output, &minVal, &maxVal);
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem with this:

```
if (countNonZero(NewData) < 1) 
{
    cout << "Eye contact occurs in this frame" << endl;
}
```

Thanks!